# Correlation matrix disturbances (shocks)

Tags: distributions, correlation

I need ideas on generating disturbances of the correlation matrix. Say, I have a n-by-n correlation matrix $C_{i,j}$. I'd like to shock it, and produce the disturbed matrix $C'_{i,j}$ and see what happens to my process after plugging it instead of the original.

UPDATE:
I must clarify that that shocks don't need to be small. So, maybe the term *disturbances* is unfortunate in my question title. For instance, if I have the 2-by-2 matrix:

```
1 1
1 1
```

Then the "largest" in some sense shock would be

```
 1 -1
-1  1
```

In n>2 dimensional case it gets a bit complicated, because due to constraints, not every matrix can be considered a correlation matrix. So, I'm looking for a way to disturb my initial matrix in some regular fashion, where the shock can be "large" or "small".

Comment: But if you allow arbitrarily large deviations, *any* correlation matrix could be considered a "disturbance" of your original correlation matrix.

Comment: @A.Donda, yes. So, I need to be able to set how large is deviation somehow. Also, it's not that easy to generate a correlation matrix, because not every symmetric matrix is positive definite

Comment: Have you found a good approach for this? I am in a somewhat similar situation where I need to transfer past changes in a correlation parameter to scenarios to be applied to current correlation level. I thought about using Fisher transformation, but it seems to give somewhat counter-intuitive behaviour. Could you share with us what you found? Thanks

Comment: @Confounded, I haven't found a good way of doing this yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider drawing your disturbed matrices from the [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) $W(V, n)$ with your original correlation matrix as the parameter $V$, and then rescale to make sure the diagonal only contains 1s. The smaller $n$, the larger the deviations from $V$ that you can expect.

Comment: This is interesting

Comment: For now this is the path I'm taking. It doesn't answer my exact question, bit it provides me with the work around.

Comment: @Aksakal, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I will put this as an answer.

What's wrong with doing something like: $C^\prime = (1-p)\cdot C + pI$, where $p$ is some small-ish value and $I$ is the identity matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You need a tranformation function of correlation coefficient that make it becomes normal distribution. May be starting from the statical testing of r would help.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @W.W.. This is hard to follow & seems rather incomplete. At present, I think it is more of a comment than an answer. Can you elaborate on it? Since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users.